# android grid view set column width

Tags: android, gridview

I am having trouble controlling the size of the columns in my
GridView.

The first column is only 3-4 chars and the other 4 columns
are 5-8 chars.

For some reason, **all the columns are the same width**,
leaving a huge amount of spacing after the first column and wrapping
the text inside the others.

**Is there a way, I can set the width of
individual columns in the grid view?**

In an ideal world, gridview
would work like an html table, where the smaller columns are shrunk to
fit the data and larger columns expand as necessary.

Any ideas would
be helpful